# aws lambda permission to IAM usergroup using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-sam

I need create a way for execute especific lambdas for specific IAM users, then i am doing:

I am creating a Usergroup in cloudformation:

```
Resources:
  XXXGroup:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Group
```

And after I am creating a policy and add the policy to my UserGroup

```
UsersXPolicies:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      Groups:
        - !Ref XXXGroup
      PolicyDocument: 
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            -
              Effect: "Allow"
              Action:
                - "lambda:*"
              Resource:
                - !Sub arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:MyFunction
                - !Sub arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:MyFunction2
      PolicyName: xxx-access-policy
```

I try first only with "lambda:InvokeFunction" but it not works, then I try with lambda:* but it not works

After I am creating a user:

```
XXUser:
    Type: AWS::IAM::User
    Properties:
      UserName: xxx.user
      LoginProfile:
        Password: l98GaTc9xzT9
        PasswordResetRequired: true
      Path: /
```

And finally i am adding the user to my usergroup:

```
USerAdditionX:
    Type: AWS::IAM::UserToGroupAddition
    Properties: 
      GroupName: !Ref XXXGroup
      Users: 
        - !Ref XXUser
```

But after login with my new user i am getting the following error when i go to lambda service:

- User: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:user/xx.user is not authorized to perform: lambda:GetAccountSettings on resource: * because no identity-based policy allows the lambda:GetAccountSettings action

Access to specific lambdas from my new user

Comment: Posted a explanation as to why your lambda is not working, still unclear?

Comment: The problem is not the lambda, the problem is the user that i am creating, I am trying to limit the access to a group of users to execute a specific lambdas.

But when I do the login with the user, The user can not see the lambda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't limit the visibility for the list of all the Lambda Functions (there is also the same "problem" on EC2 Instances and S3 Buckets permissions policy), so your user cannot interact with the Lambda because the policy that you provided have the condition on the specific resource, but he need the full read-only capability even to see the function.

You should add at least an Allow statement on **lambda:ListFunctions** and **lambda:GetAccountSettings** for Resource "*" (so on every Lambda of your account), as stated [here](https://aws.amazon.com/it/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/granular-access-lambda/).

You could also, as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-identity-based.html), add the standard **AWSLambda_ReadOnlyAccess** policy to your group.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that lambda get its permission from a role.Policies are attached to role.

You need to attach your policies to a role and then attach a role to lambda.

or another way to solve this would be using indentity based IAM policies for lambda where user will gets its permissions to the group he belongs to. Simple add relevant permissions to group.

Please read about lambda execution role over [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html)

Comment: But using role, in cloudformation i don't find how can I attach a role to user

Comment: There are 2 questions one is to give lambda permission which I told, the another is creating user and adding permission to that user with cloudformation, is it possible to create another question?

Comment: I have only one question that is: Create a group of users with permission to specific lambdas, and you said me that is not possible using a usergroup, Is possible using a role if I understand. But it not solve my question that is How can I limit the access to lambdas to some users.

Comment: Had a similar issue, and all I had to do was add the lambda policy `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambda_FullAccess` to the group assigned to the user that was having the issue.